# Matching multiple occurrences of values in 2 columns in excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I currently need to match values in 2 columns. Data is currently set up as follows:

```
Debit        Credit
5000
             6000
6000
6000
3000         5000
```

and so on.

what i am trying to achieve is highlighting the number of debits and credits which match ie in the above example, there are 2 debits for 6000 but only one credit so only one 6000 should be highlighted in each column.

any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using conditional formatting, I've my data in H1:I6, using the following

On the debit column

```
=AND(COUNTIF($I$2:I$6,H2)<COUNTIF($H$2:$H$6,H2),ROW(H2)-1=MATCH(H2,$H$2:$H$6,0))
```

On the credit column, switch the count, from comparing I to H, to comparing H to I

`=AND(COUNTIF($I$2:$I$6,I2)<COUNTIF($H$2:$H$6,I2),ROW(I2)-1=MATCH(I2,$I$2:$I$6,0))`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Macro1()
    iRowMax = 6
    iColDeb = 1
    iColCre = 2
    For iRowD = 2 To iRowMax
        For iRowC = 2 To iRowMax
            If Cells(iRowC, iColCre).Interior.Color <> 65535 Then
                If Cells(iRowC, iColCre) = Cells(iRowD, iColDeb) Then
                    Cells(iRowC, iColCre).Interior.Color = 65535
                    Cells(iRowD, iColDeb).Interior.Color = 65535
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next iRowC
    Next iRowD
End Sub
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code only answer. It would help future visitors. Code only answers are often downvoted and may be deleted.